# changing foreground image programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I change the image of a foreground of a textbox programmatically? Right now I have:

```
box.setForeground(R.drawable.image)
```

but it says that 'R.drawable.image' is an int, not a drawable. How can I convert it into a drawable?

Comment: Use this to get drawable from image id `ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.image)`

Comment: @LiemVo I get an error on 'context' that says: "Classifier 'context' does not have a companion object and thus needs to be initialized here"

Comment: You can pass the context from somewhere like Activity, Fragment or use the context of your view. 
`ContextCompat.getDrawable(box.context, R.drawable.image)`

Answer (score 0):

Because I land in this question for something simple:

in Kotlin

`box.foreground = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable. image)`